# Passing kwargs to a function with multiprocessing.pool.map for pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing, pool, keyword-argument

I have written a function that takes in a dataframe with keywords arguments as shown below:

```
df1 = df1.apply(add_data_ip2, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

The process takes 20 minutes. the function add_data_ip2 takes in a dataframe and reads the stock symbol under the "Ticker" column and does an api call to retrieve financial info and manipulates the data through math to calculate a score. The score is under saved in the "Score" column of the same df. The function returns the same dataframe.

The df contains approximately 1500 ticker symbols and I am trying to run the following parallel processing code to reduce the waiting time, but with no luck. The function keeps running with no indication of any output. Can anyone advise what is the problem? Is there anything wrong with the way I am passing in the kwargs into the function. Have tried searching stackoverflow for answers with no luck. Appreciate the help.

```
from functools import partial
mapfunc = partial(add_data_ip2, axis=1, result_type="expand")

p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
df1= p.map(mapfunc, df1)
df1
```

Another alternative block also doesn't give any output either.

```
from multiprocessing import  Pool
    
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=4):
        df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
        pool = Pool(n_cores)
        df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return df

train = parallelize_dataframe(df1, mapfunc)'
```

Comment: I lost in your code - better create minimal working code with example data directly in code.

Comment: `Pool` has also other functions - like [starmap](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap). `Map` runs `func( [1,2,3] )` but `starmap` should run as `func(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: I'm not sure but for me your `partial` is wrong. As for me you can't send `df1` to `partial(add_data_ip2,...)` to run it as `df1.apply(add_data_ip2,...)`. You should create normal function `def func(dfX): dfX.apply(add_data_ip2,...)`. Besides `axis=1, result_type="expand"` are parameters for `apply()` but using them in `partial` you try to send them to `add_data_ip2`

Answer (score 0):

As for me your `partial` is wrong.

You can't send `df` to partial `partial(add_data_ip2,...)` and run as `df.apply(add_data_ip2, ...)` because `partial` will try to run it as `add_data_ip2(..., df)`

Other problem: `axis=1, result_type="expand"` are parameters for `df.apply()`  but `partial` will run it as `add_data_ip2(..., axis=1, result_type="expand")`

As for me you should define normal function

```
def mapfunc(dfx):
    return dfx.apply(add_data_ip2, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

or `lambda`

```
mapfunc = lambda dfx: dfx.apply(add_data_ip2, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

But as I know `Pool` can't work with `lambda` because it has to save function and data in `pickle` and later `process` has to read it - but `pickle` can't save `lambda`

---

Code which I used for tests

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

data = {
    'A': [1,2,3], 
    'B': [4,5,6], 
    'C': [7,8,9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print('--- original ---')
print(df)

def add_data_ip2(row):
    row['A'] += 10
    row['B'] += 100
    row['C'] += 1000
    return row

# --- test 1 ---
#new_df = df.apply(add_data_ip2, axis=1, result_type="expand")
#print(new_df)  # OK

# --- test 2 ---
#mapfunc = partial(add_data_ip2, axis=1, result_type="expand")
#new_df = mapfunc(df)  # ERROR
#print(new_df)
    
# --- test 3 ---
#mapfunc = lambda df: df.apply(add_data_ip2, axis=1, result_type="expand")
#new_df = mapfunc(df)  # OK
#print(new_df)

# --- test 4 ---
def mapfunc(df):
    return df.apply(add_data_ip2, axis=1, result_type="expand")

new_df = mapfunc(df)  # OK
print('--- mapfunc ---')
print(new_df)

# --- test Pool ---

p = Pool()

parts = np.array_split(df, 4)

results = p.map(mapfunc, parts)

print('--- Poll results ---')
for item in results:
    print(item)
    print('---')
    
print('--- concat new df ---')    
new_df = pd.concat(results)
print(new_df)
```